# background image just be seen in child div

Tags: html, css

i have a parent div with background image and another div inside it. i want background image of parent div only be seen in child div (like an open window).

```css
.parent {
    width:800px;
     height:600px;
     background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
}
 .child{
     width:50%;
     margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi There ! It is not clear what do you want to achieve my friend ;) Can you share your image to show what you trying to achieve :)

Comment: in fact i have multiple child div that through them a part of full screen image (a big cat image) in parent div can be seen. i need a layer that cover all over the parent except child divs.

Comment: I am afraid It is not yet clear dear :) Do you know https://imgur.com/ just upload ur desired output image... only then I can come up with some solution :) Specifications not clear yet my friend

Comment: So basically, you want the background image to fill the entire parent but not the children?

Comment: this is exactly what i need: https://imgur.com/Xpa5IKk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want an image in backgound and you want to display it inside a child div.

To implement this, you can use WebKit's image masking.

```css
.demo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}

.demo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.demo:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5607/5091629.6b/0_612e6_b9039c0d_M.jpg)
    no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.1;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.demo .has-mask {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(10px, 190px, 190px, 10px);
}

.demo:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
    <img src="https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5607/5091629.6b/0_612e6_b9039c0d_M.jpg" alt="" class="has-mask">
</div>
```

More details here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I can not comment yet. But as far as I understand your question, you want to mask the image of the parent by the child.

Maybe you can achieve this by using the information provided here:

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

But maybe, if you visualize your problem, there is no need for masking or cliping and can be solved way easier.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
.parent {
  width:800px;
  height:600px; 
  background-image: URL(...); 
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again. It says in the child div.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: My bad, I read it like the image is already seen only in child div and he wants it to be seen in whole parent div. In case this was the question, this would be an answer.